# Excel Count unique records that match criteria in multiple rows

Tags: excel, unique

In Excel I have a list of members by year and whether they paid or not in each year. I'm trying to determine the number of members who live in NY and have paid in BOTH 2019 and 2021. In the example below, only Mike and Jane meet the criteria. Because the "AND" condition is in the same column, I could not find a similar example.  Thank you.

| Member | Year | Paid Status | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2018 | Paid | NY |
| John | 2019 | Paid | NY |
| John | 2020 | Paid | NY |
| John | 2021 | Not Paid | NY |
| Mike | 2018 | Paid | NY |
| **Mike** | **2019** | **Paid** | **NY** |
| Mike | 2020 | Paid | NY |
| **Mike** | **2021** | **Paid** | **NY** |
| Mary | 2018 | Paid | CA |
| Mary | 2019 | Not Paid | CA |
| Mary | 2020 | Paid | CA |
| Mary | 2021 | Paid | CA |
| Jane | 2018 | Not Paid | NY |
| **Jane** | **2019** | **Paid** | **NY** |
| Jane | 2020 | Not Paid | NY |
| **Jane** | **2021** | **Paid** | **NY** |
| Tom | 2018 | Paid | CA |
| Tom | 2019 | Paid | CA |
| Tom | 2020 | Not Paid | CA |
| Tom | 2021 | Paid | CA |

Comment: Countifs() with and() should work.

Comment: @SolarMike I would be interested in how you make it work with those two formula.  At this moment I cannot think of a way, but my brain is on a little overload at the moment.

Comment: @SolarMike Could you please show me how to combine those formulas to work? I can't think of a way either.  Thanks!

Comment: Simplest thing to do is apply filters

Comment: @Jeff well perhaps you could have waited before accepting an answer. Not saying mine is the best but would have liked to be in the running as it were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dynamic formula in Office 365 `LET()` and `FILTER()`  We can return the correct value:

```
=LET(mem,A2:A21,yr,B2:B21,sts,C2:C21,st,D2:D21,fst,FILTER(mem,(yr=2021)*(sts="paid")*(st="NY")),scnd,FILTER(mem,(yr=2019)*(sts="paid")*(st="NY")),COUNT(MATCH(fst,scnd,0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column `Paid Code` based on the Paid Status:

> =IF([@[Paid Status]]="Paid";1;0)

Then build a pivot table using:

- `Member` as Raws
- `Year` as Columns
- The Sum of the `Paid Code` as Values

Then you have a new table where you can easly extract the metrics you deisre.

Answer (score 0):

Well some commenters suggested that it might not work, so here is my offering, where cell I1 has the result:

[image]

In cell G2 (count for one year):

```
COUNTIFS(A2:A21,F2,D2:D21,F$8,C2:C21,G$8,B2:B21,H$8)
```

In cell H2 (count for second year):

```
COUNTIFS(A2:A21,F2,D2:D21,F$8,C2:C21,G$8,B2:B21,I$8)
```

In cell I2 (and to make sure both are present):

```
IF(AND(G2,H2),1,0)
```

The list of names in column F could be generated by the use of unique().

The data in F8:I8 could be with data validation to get different results as needed.

I always think several small functions are easier to control than one longer function...

And the table G2:H6 can be reduced to 4 cells with:

```
IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A2:A21,F2,D2:D21,F$8,C2:C21,G$8,B2:B21,H$8),COUNTIFS(A2:A21,F2,D2:D21,F$8,C2:C21,G$8,B2:B21,I$8)),1,"")
```

Comment: @ScottCraner well, takes more cells but does work.